# Difference between note id and universal id

Tags: lotus-notes

I did search but I still don't have a clear idea. I used the "universal id" (UNID) many times but never "note id" so want to know the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *universal ID* uniquely identifies a document **across all replicas** of a database.
The universal ID is a **32**-character combination of hexadecimal digits (0-9, A-F).

[If two documents in replica databases share the same universal ID, the documents are replicas. If you modify the UNID of an existing document, it becomes a new document.](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_UNIVERSALID_PROPERTY_DOC.html)

The *note ID* uniquely identifies a document **within a particular database**.
The note ID is an **8**-character combination of letters and numbers.

[A note ID represents the location of a document within a specific database file, so documents which are replicas of one another generally have different note IDs.](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_NOTEID_PROPERTY.html)

Comment: It should also be noted that it is possible for the noteid of a given document to change during many routine administrative procedures. Code should never depend on it to remain the same. I.e., definitely do not store noteids as a way to maintain relationships between documents.

Comment: And although it is much more rare for administrative procedures to change documents' UNIDs, there are cases where this can happen as well. E.g. documents have been accidentally deleted and the deletions have fully replicated, so they are restored from a non-replica copy or simply re-created. Given this possibility, storing UNIDs as a way to maintain relationships between documents is not 100% safe either.